# Platform Cache for ISVs

Tags: isv, platform-cache

I have used [Platform Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_cache_namespace_overview.htm) as a customer a while ago but never heard any story about ISVs using it. So, I'm wondering: is there any ISV out there using it and if there is any, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably a good question for Partner Success. But I know myself and other ISVs I talked to were put off by the cost - it was pretty expensive to buy cache dedicated to my namespace since it was a per customer expense, rather than something I could just buy once for my app and distribute it with it (but that could have changed since I last inquired)

It was also quite hard to build apps with it, since you needed it enabled in any org you were developing in (rather than just having a single customer instance with Sandboxes) But a recent [exchange](https://twitter.com/WadeWegner/status/1100870096245776384) on Twitter said they were actively working on this second pain point. If so, I might be more inclined to revisit it, and/or also consider seeing if I can use the customer's default cache with my app, since most customers are not making full use of the default cache they get with their enterprise org.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am the CEO of theCodery and we are designing an ISV package with platform cache leveraged. I have discluded PC before due to the limitations as previously specified by BritishBoyinDC. Our design principles that led us to platform cache are:

1. Non-human managed, variable data that changes infrequently but must be delivered rapidly for a dependent service or services.
2. Lightweight (fits in platform cache capability) JSON schema for that data
3. Ability to refresh that data on either regular interval or inbound external service call.
4. Packageable and sellable in an ISV context.

Targeted deployment of said application will be after Summer 19 go-live so TBD on final implementation as alignment is needed with supported platform cache feature-scope.