# Provider Free Capacity

Tags: managed-package, 2gp, platform-cache

I've updated the cachePartition metadata of a 2GP package, which has previously passed security review.

```
<platformCachePartitionTypes>
    ...
    <allocatedPartnerCapacity>2</allocatedPartnerCapacity>
    <cacheType>Organization</cacheType>
</platformCachePartitionTypes>
<platformCachePartitionTypes>
    ...
    <allocatedPartnerCapacity>1</allocatedPartnerCapacity>
    <cacheType>Session</cacheType>
</platformCachePartitionTypes>
```

Next, I've set the sourceApiVersion in sfdx-project.json to 51.0.

After that, I've built the package with a new package version, however when I install a package on an Enterprise test production org - I cannot see if any free cache is allocated for the package when I open Org Cache.

Is there a way I can tell that cache is available for the package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Platform Cache for ISVs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256577/platform-cache-for-isvs)

Comment: Thank you, @sfdcfox, it is somewhat useful, but it doesn't answer my question.